# SharePoint List form customized with Power Apps displays very little in size although the Preview screen displays perfectly

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-form, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, splist-custom-newform

I have a SP list with customized form through power apps[canvas app]. When I go to powerapps.com and preview the form [set size 1185x790(potraitxlarge)], it displays the form with perfect size. When I published the form and tried to click on the New button over the list view, it renders the customized form , but the form size is very little with right-side like a small mobile view.

One more thing I noticed is when I directly typed the list newform URL [/newform.aspx],it displays the page with only "submit" and "Cancel" button at the top and no control is getting rendered within the page.

Please help me resolving the issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase the size of your SharePoint list form.

- Edit your existing SharePoint list item form with Power Apps
- Inside Power Apps Studio, Click File > Settings
- Change the width to match your requirements
- Save and publish the form

[image]

Now you will see that your SharePoint list item form is much wider.

[image]